# Create overlay w/text when I hover over img

Tags: jquery, html, css

My HTML includes the following:

```
<section class="row-1">
  <div class="column-12"></div>    
</section>
```

In the SASS I have it setup so that when I hover over .column-12, the background-image is replaced with a background-color. Here is my SASS:

```
.row-1 .column-12
  background-image: url(/images/image-yellow.jpg)
  position: relative
  &:hover
   background-color: rgba(76,193,171,1)
  &:before
   position: absolute
   top: 0
   right: 0
   bottom: 0
   left: 0
   background-color: inherit
   content: ''
```

In addition to having the background-image removed AND having the background-color change (which it already does fine), I want to have text slide in from the left hand corner when I hover over the .column-12 element. So in the end, when you hover over the image, the background color should be rgba(76,193,171) and there should be text that slides in from the left.

I fooled around with lots of different ways, still no success. Any help would be great. Even if the text just fades in... that would be okay too.

Comment: Where is the text coming from? What part of your HTML is the text in?

Comment: That's what I'm struggling with, I don't know where to put the text to make this work the easiest. Before, I had <div><h4>This is a test</h4></div>  right under <div class="column-12></div>... but I couldn't seem to get that to work

Comment: take a look at this CSS3 tutorial. You should be able to use the `transition` property so that when changes are made to the container, like on hover they follow the transition. Then, you can also use the `transform: translate()` to move some object on hover. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `transform: translateX(-100%);` for you text node then use a transition to `transform: translateX(0);` on hover of your `.column-12`. Also, add a `overflow:hidden;` so you only see it within the `.column-12` div

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc1dbt41/1/) for an example.

HTML

```
<section class="row-1">
  <div class="column-12">
    <h3>
       Text text text.
    </h3>
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.row-1 .column-12 {
  background-image: url(https://placehold.it/200x200);
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  width: 200px; /*for demo*/
  height: 200px; /*for demo*/
}

.row-1 .column-12 h3 {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 350ms ease;
}

.row-1 .column-12:hover {
  background: rgba(76, 193, 171, 1)
}

.row-1 .column-12:hover h3 {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.row-1 .column-12:before {
  position: absolute top: 0 right: 0 bottom: 0 left: 0 background-color: inherit content: ''
}
```

Comment: Might I suggest doing it with simple `left` and positioning instead of `transform`? I edited [your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qc1dbt41/2/). Reason being, it'll degrade more gracefully than it would in a browser that doesn't support `transform`. I also took the liberty of making the background slide with and be semi-transparent via `::before`.... mostly because I didn't catch OP didn't want that. Heh. Still, you can do an opacity switch on the background so it fades in instead of the harsh transition easier with the "replacement" background on the pseudoelement.

Comment: @abluejelly Sure that works too. It is probably closer to the effect the OP is going for

Comment: Thanks a lot! Finally got it working. I really appreciate your help and I've learned a lot from the help of both of you.